# GridSearch with SkLearn Pipeline not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I implemented a custom PCA for a subset of features whose column names start with a digit and after PCA, join them with rest of features. And then implement a GBRT model in grid search as a sklearn pipeline. The pipeline by itself works fine but with GridSearch, it seems to be taking a subset of data each time giving out errors. The custom PCA is:

```
class PartialPCA(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

def __init__(self, n_components=0.9995, svd_solver='full', mask=None):
    # mask should contain selected cols. Suppose it is boolean to avoid code overhead
    self.n_components = n_components
    self.svd_solver = svd_solver
    self.mask = mask

def fit(self, X, y=None):
    print(X.shape)
    print(type(X))
    X.to_csv('InitialX.csv')
    print(X.isnull().values.any())
    X.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    self.remaining_cols = X[[i for i in X.columns if i[0].isdigit() is False]].copy()
    self.pca = PCA(n_components=self.n_components, svd_solver=self.svd_solver)
    mask = self.mask if self.mask is not None else slice(None)
    self.pca.fit(X[mask])
    return self

def transform(self, X, y=None):
    mask = self.mask if self.mask is not None else slice(None)
    pca_transformed = self.pca.transform(X[mask])
    if self.mask is not None:
        print(pca_transformed.shape)
        col_no = pca_transformed.shape[1]
        pca_transformed = pd.DataFrame(data=pca_transformed, columns=range(1, col_no + 1))
        X = pd.concat(objs=(self.remaining_cols, pca_transformed), axis=1)
        X.to_csv('X.csv')
        print(X.isnull().values.any())
        print(pca_transformed.isnull().values.any())
        print(self.remaining_cols.isnull().values.any())
        return X
    else:
        return pca_transformed
```

And then it is called by

```
mask = [i for i in trainPredTrans.columns if i[0].isdigit() is True]
pca = PartialPCA(n_components=0.9995, svd_solver='full', mask=mask)
print(pca)
gbrt = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=10)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('pca', pca), ('gbrt', gbrt)])
estimator = model_selection.GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid=[dict(pca__svd_solver=['auto','full','arpack']),
                                               dict(gbrt__learning_rate=[0.1,  0.2,  0.3, 0.4,  0.5],
                                                                    gbrt__loss=["ls", "lad", "huber", "quantile"],
                                                                    gbrt__max_depth=[3, 4, 5],
                                                                    gbrt__min_samples_split=[2, 3, 4])])
print(estimator)
trainPredTrans.to_csv('trainPredTrans.csv')
estimator.fit(trainPredTrans, trainTarget.values.ravel())
```

The input train dataframe is of shape (1198, 1248) but inside the function, when I print X.shape, it is (798, 1248) and after fit it becomes (798, 97) and seems to iterate again and gives an error saying input has nan values which occured due to concatenating two different sized dataframes(but whch should have same sized).
I spent a lot of hours but couldn't figure out the issue and why it would seem to work without gridsearch. It seems like the Gridsearch is using the gbrt params to iterate over pca which shouldn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of the length of train and test data. GridSearcCV will split the data into train and test depending on the cv param. So length of train data will be more, which is saved into `self.remaining_cols` When the test data goes there to `transform()`, you try to append the original `self.remaining_cols` which have more samples to the new data and hence the new data is appended with `Nans` to match the length.

To solve this, I would recommend you to move the `self.remaining_cols` logic to `transform()` instead of `fit()`. Something like this:

```
...
...
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    X.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    self.pca = PCA(n_components=self.n_components, svd_solver=self.svd_solver)
    mask = self.mask if self.mask is not None else slice(None)
    self.pca.fit(X[mask])
    return self

def transform(self, X, y=None):
    mask = self.mask if self.mask is not None else slice(None)
    X.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    pca_transformed = self.pca.transform(X[mask])
    if self.mask is not None:
        col_no = pca_transformed.shape[1]
        pca_transformed = pd.DataFrame(data=pca_transformed, columns=range(1, col_no + 1))
        self.remaining_cols = X[[i for i in X.columns if i[0].isdigit() is False]].copy()
        X = pd.concat(objs=(self.remaining_cols, pca_transformed), axis=1)
        return X
    else:
        return pca_transformed
```

Also, to do these kind of things, where only a subset of columns are selected to some processing, I would recommend you to look into FeatureUnion and ItemSelector as explained in this example:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html

**Note:** I observed that you defined the parameter space as two dicts. You should not that sending list of dicts into the GridSearchCV will make them exclusive. That means that they will be calculated separately and not in combination with one other.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You forgot to put the change you mentioned in the code but I get what you said and it's working perfectly fine now. I chose to do pca with dataframe instead of arrays as I want a dynamic pca code which chooses only the columns starting with a digit instead of fixed positioning in an array